# Eliminar registro con ventana Modal - PHP

Tags: php, modal

Estoy intentando agregarle una ventana modal de confirmacion de eliminacion de un registro, me logra salir la modal de ventana pero al darle cualquiera de los botones la pagina se queda como sombreada y no pasa nada

este es mi codigo de la tabla, donde los botones estan en el apartado ACCION

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="example1" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                            
                                                <th>Fecha Requerimiento</th>
                                                <th>Nº Oficio</th>
                                                <th>Entidad</th>
                                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                                <th>Identidad</th>
                                                <th>Cliente</th>
                                                <th>Cliente Producto Activo</th>
                                                <th>Solo Perfil</th>
                                                <th>Observaciones</th>
                                                <th>Accion</th>
                                                
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        
                                        <tbody>
                                            <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                                
                                                <tr>
                                                
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['fecha_req']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['no_oficio']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['entidad']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['identidad']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['cliente']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['cliente_producto_activo']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['solo_perfil']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['observaciones']; ?></td>
                                                    <td>
            <a href="#" data-href="01_req_sec_2021_delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>    </a>
                                    
            <a  href="01_req_sec_2021_edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>"><i class="fas fa-marker"></i></a>   
                                                    
</tr>
<?php } ?>
                                        
</tbody>
</table>
```

Este es mi codigo de Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Eliminar Registro
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Esta seguro de Eliminar este Registro?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el script que estoy usando

```
<script>
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
        </script>
```

Asi me aparece la modal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al darle a cualquier boton se me queda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se cual sera el error o faltara algo

el codigo para eliminar un registro que estoy usando es este:

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $query = "DELETE FROM req_secretaria_2021 WHERE id = $id";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  if(!$result) {
    die("Query Failed.");
  }

  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Borrado Correctamente';
  $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'danger';
  header('Location: 01_req_sec_2021.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Listo ya lo hice

Comment: Actualiza tu publicación por fa. Por otro, intentaste en vez de usar una clase, ponerle el btn-ok como un id? .

Comment: Y que es lo que quieres eliminar?

Comment: Estoy intentando eliminar un registro, ya tengo el codigo que elimina, sin embargo la modal al darle a uno de esos botones no pasa nada la pantalla se queda asi

Comment: Listo agregado.

Answer (score 0):

**Pregunta: Que librerias y versiones tanto de CSS como Jquery estas usando? Ya que puede ser ello lo que este ocasionando el problema**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <!--Las librerias de estilo-->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
      <!--Resto de operaciones-->
    </body>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).